# Has someone idea how to DragAndDrop this specifig (noUiSlider) with selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, drag-and-drop, slider, action

I am trying to use the following code to move a slider with `Selenium Webdriver`, but nothing happens. I tried the same code for a different slider and it works. Slider is here `("Range")`: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/

I am using browser Chrome, Selenium v3.6.0

How else can I move a slider?

```
        IWebElement knob = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/section[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div"));

        //try1
        Actions a1 = new Actions(driver);
        a1.DragAndDropToOffset(knob, 30, 0).Build().Perform();
        //try2
        Actions a2 = new Actions(driver);
        a2.ClickAndHold(knob).MoveByOffset(30, 0).Release().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Can't you just change the values of the attributes? check this image that highlights the values that changed while dragging https://ibb.co/dSJYdk
aria-valuenow eventually is what you want

Comment: What version of selenium are you using?  Seem that the latest driver versions don't fully support the Actions api.

Answer (score 1):

One method you can use is to just click the slider at the position you want it set to.

Since you are likely to reuse this code, I would put it in a function. That function would take in the element to be clicked (the slider) and the relative position with which to click. Think of the relative position like a %... 0.5 is half way, 0.1 is 1/10th and so on. The function just gets the width of the element and then applies the % to the width to get the position to click horizontally. The vertical position is just half the height of the element (so you click in the middle vertically).

```
static void SetRange(IWebElement e, double range)
{
    int point = (int)(e.Size.Width * range);
    new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(e, point, e.Size.Height / 2).Click().Build().Perform();
}
```

To call it, just use

```
SetRange(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("slider-range")), 0.1); // 0.1 is 10%
SetRange(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("slider-range")), 0.5); // 0.5 is 50% or halfway
```